# Issues seen during utf-7 conversion

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

Python : 2.7

I need to convert to utf-7 before I go ahead, so I have used below code in python 2.7 interpreter:

```
>>> mbox = u'한국의'
>>> mbox.encode('utf-7').replace(b"+", b"&").replace(b"/", b",")
'&1VytbcdY-'
```

Same code when I use in my python script as shown below, the output for mbox is `b'&Ti1W,XaE'` instead of `b'&Ti1W,XaE-'` i.e. "-" at end of string is missing when running as a script instead of interpreter.

```
    mbox = "b'" +  mbox + "'"
    print mbox
    mbox = mbox.encode('utf-7').replace(b"+", b"&").replace(b"/", b",")
    print mbox
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from [Wikipedia's description of UTF-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7):

> Other characters must be encoded in UTF-16 (hence U+10000 and higher would be encoded into surrogates), big-endian (hence higher-order bits appear first), and then in modified Base64. The start of these blocks of modified Base64 encoded UTF-16 is indicated by a + sign. The end is indicated by any character not in the modified Base64 set. If the character after the modified Base64 is a - (ASCII hyphen-minus) then it is consumed by the decoder and decoding resumes with the next character. Otherwise decoding resumes with the character after the base64.

Any block of encoded characters must end with a non-Base64 character. If the string includes such a character, it will be used, otherwise `-` is added to the end of the block. Your first example includes a `-` for this reason. Your second example doesn't need one because `'` is not part of the [Base64 character set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

If your intent is to create a Python literal that creates a valid UTF-7 string, just do things in a different order.

```
mbox = b"b'" + mbox.encode('utf-7').replace(b"+", b"&").replace(b"/", b",") + b"'"
```